# Vite + React : Outputting each js build file next to the html file that uses it

Tags: reactjs, build, vite, rollupjs

I've been using vite with a multiple entrypoint and multiple output setup, but i need to be able to build each js file in the same folder as the html file that uses it, because the framework i'm developing on forbids access to other folders than `/graphics` or `/dashboard`.

For the moment, it gets generated in a separate `/assets` folder.

**vite.config.js :**

```
export default defineConfig({
  root: 'src',
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        dashboard: resolve(__dirname, 'src/dashboard/index.html'),
        graphics: resolve(__dirname, 'src/graphics/index.html'),
      },
      output: {
        dashboard: resolve(__dirname, 'dashboard/index.html'),
        graphics: resolve(__dirname, 'graphics/index.html') 
      }
    },
  },
})
```

**Current build folder structure :**

```
├── dashboard
│   └── index.html
│
├── graphics
│   └── index.html
└── assets
    ├── graphicsfile.js
    └── dashboardfile.js
```

**Wanted build folder structure :**

```
├── dashboard
│   ├── index.html
│   └── dashboardfile.js
│
└── graphics
    ├── index.html
    └── graphicsfile.js
```

Is there a way to build this the way i want to ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it in the build.outDir and build.assetDir options.
https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-outdir